# Pause TeamCity projects while others are executing

Tags: teamcity

I’d like to be able to specify that one build project should pause while another specified project is running.

In my case, there is a project #1 that builds and deploys compiled code to our servers, and a project #2 that performs Selenium tests on that deployed code. The tests can take several minutes, and I’d like to make sure that the build-and-deploy doesn’t happen in the middle of testing.

So, I’d like to pause #1 (build) while #2 (test) is running.

Dependencies or Triggers do not offer this option, as far as I can tell. Can this be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a request on TeamCity issue tracker [TW-3798](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3798). You are welcome to vote and watch.

This functionality is currently being developed. For now you can use one of the features provided by [GroovyPlugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Groovy+plug) called StartBuildPrecondition. To ensure that only one build is executed add the same write lock to both of the builds

Answer (score 0):

The way we do this is by restricting them to one build agent.  They you are insured that only one runs at a time.